# How to speed up a for loop?

Tags: python

I have this loop:

```
for s in sales:
    salezip = sales[s][1]
    salecount = sales[s][0]
    for d in deals:
        dealzip = deals[d][1]
        dealname = deals[d][0]
        for zips in ziplist:
            if salezip == zips[0] and dealzip == zips[1]:
                distance = zips[2]
                print "MATCH FOUND"
                if not salesdict.has_key(dealname):
                    salesdict[dealname] = [dealname,dealzip,salezip,salecount,distance]
                else:
                    salesdict[dealname][3] += salecount
```

And it is taking FOREVER to run. The sales dictionary has 13k entries, the deals dictionary has 1000 entries, and the ziplist has 1.8M entries. It is obviously very slow when it hits the ziplist part, I have it set to print "MATCH FOUND" when it successfully find a match, and it hasn't printed in over 20 minutes. What can I do to make this move quicker?

Purpose of the code:

Loop through sales data which contains the amount of apples sold and the location of the purchase, pull the location and quantity info. Then, loop through apple dealers, find their location and their name. Then, loop through the ziplist data which shows distance between zip codes, sorted in ascending order of distance. The second it finds a match of the sales zip and dealer zip, it adds them to a dictionary with all of their information.

Comment: What is your code trying to do, can you give us some example of how it's suppose to work? Provide us a [MCVE]

Comment: @MooingRawr added an explanation

Comment: O(n^3) algorithm. You should probably work on fixing the algorithm complexity.

Comment: Maybe consider moving your data into a database or a dataframe of some sort, so your look ups would be faster.

Comment: Include some sample data from `sales`, `deals`, and `ziplist`.

Comment: You're blaming the for loop? You told it to do a simple task this many times: 13000 * 1000 * 1800000. Maybe the sales object could have told you who the dealer was in that sale? But your zip code lookup seems to be the worst part. What is that, a chart with all pairs of zipcodes plus a median distance, with a linear lookup?

Comment: You _absolutely must_ index the contents of `ziplist` by sale and dealer values.

Comment: It might be faster to just store a coordinate for the zipcode, and compute the distance between two zipcodes. You are doing linear lookup now, so the ziplist is hurting more than it helps.  If you need to precompute, use a dict for faster lookup.

Comment: I'm still not sure why you want to look at every dealer, for every sale. I feel like a sale was handled by exactly 1 dealer, so why look at the others? Is the goal to decide what sales were actually using the closest dealer? I guess my question is -- What's the actual goal?

Answer (score 2):

Having `ziplist` as an actual list of (zip1, zip2, distance) is insane - you want a data structure where you can directly find the desired item, without having to loop through the entire data set.

A dictionary with (zip1, zip2) as the key, and the distance as the value, would be enormously faster.  Note that you'd need to insert each distance under the key (zip2, zip1) as well, to handle lookups in the opposite direction.  Alternatively, you could sort [zip1, zip2] into numeric order before using it as a key (both on insert and lookup), so that it doesn't matter which order they are specified in.

Comment: This is a good idea if your code is building up the `ziplist` in the first place. If you're pulling the `ziplist` from an external source, processing it into a dictionary with a sorted tuple key might not be saving you as much time as just processing it once and speeding up the lookups of the smaller data sets.

Comment: @user108471 No, the point of indexing based on the zip values is to eliminate the need to loop through 1.8 million indices.

Comment: @RobertOliveira I understand that. If you can index the data source by zip values from the beginning, you save yourself the need to do a loop over 1.8M indices. If you receive the ziplist as a list from an external source, you would have to build a new data structure indexed by zip values, which would force you to loop over the whole data set.

Comment: You misunderstand. There is no such thing as fast lookup in a list. This answer says use a dict, which provides fast lookup.

Comment: @user108471 looping through 1.8 million indices once is trivial, doing it 13000 * 1000 times is the issue.

Comment: @KennyOstrom I understand the problem very well, but I think you are misunderstanding what I'm trying to say. The constraints of the problem are unspecified, so it's not clear whether implementing this solution means transforming the existing list into a dict, or whether we can just build a dict instead of a list to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

The best thing you can do is to reorganize your code so that you don't have to loop so many times, and you don't have to do as many look-ups. It looks to me like you're looping over `ziplist` 130k times as much as you really need to. Here are a couple ideas that might help:

First, create a way to quickly look up sale and deal information by zip rather than by name:

```
sale_by_zip = {sales[key][1]: sales[key] for key in sales}
deal_by_zip = {deals[key][1]: deals[key] for key in deals}
```

Then, make the iteration through the `ziplist` the only outer loop:

```
for zips in ziplist:
    salezip = zips[0]
    dealzip = zips[1]
    if salezip in sale_by_zip and dealzip in deal_by_zip:
        distance = zips[2]
        print "MATCH FOUND"
        dealname = deal_by_zip[dealzip][0]
        salecount = sale_by_zip[salezip][0]
        if not salesdict.has_key(dealname):
            salesdict[dealname] = [dealname,dealzip,salezip,salecount,distance]
        else:
            salesdict[dealname][3] += salecount
```

This should drastically reduce the amount of processing you need to do.

As others have noted, the structure of `ziplist` is also not the most well-suited to this problem. My suggestions assume `ziplist` is something you receive from an external source and cannot change the format of without making an extra pass over it. If you are building the `ziplist` yourself, however, consider something that would give you faster lookups.

Comment: This is a good "minimal change" answer. You don't try to fix flaws in their data structures or reasoning, but just removed the excessive loop nesting. It's not ideal, but its problems came from the OP. The syntax is odd on sales and deals so those must be from some library that overrides common operators -- pandas datasets maybe?

Comment: @KennyOstrom Yes, I tried to avoid making assumptions about what could be changed. Can you clarify what syntax you think is odd? There's nothing unusual here that wouldn't work just fine with ordinary Python dictionaries.

Comment: I was mostly just saying what is good about the answer. I mistakenly thought sales and deals were lists, so nevermind about the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The root of your problem is that you're processing the zip list multiple times - for every deal and then again for every sale.

One possibility is to reverse the order of your coding: start with the zips list, then the sales list, and finally the deals dictionary.  If you're going to iterate through something multiple times, at least iterating through the smaller dictionary would be a lot faster.

if there aren't a lot matches, perhaps using "in" would be quicker, such as `if dealzip in zips:` and then process from then.